# lodash: filter array of objects with a different array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

This question is specific to **[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs)**.

Given two arrays of objects, what is the **best way** to filter one array with the objects of the other array? I have attempted to put forth a scenario below, and the way I have gone about doing this is using two `.forEach` loops, but I would like to know if using lodash there is a better way to go about this type of filtering.

---

**Example**
The main source array of objects is `users`.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'joe', 'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 50, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 60, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 70, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 22, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 25, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];
```

The array of objects that will filter the `users` array is called `others`.

```
var others = [
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 60 },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 70},
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 22}
];
```

The desired result based on `others` filtering `users` is:

```
[
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 60, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 70, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 22, 'active': false }
];
```

Here is one way to obtain the desired result.

```
var result = [];

_.forEach(users, function (n, key) {
   _.forEach(others, function (n2, key2) {
      if (n.user === n2.user && n.age === n2.age) {
         result.push(n);
      }
   });
});

console.log(result);
```

Here is the example on jsbin.
http://jsbin.com/hapariviya/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You're trying to find duplicates based on user and age?

Comment: @CoryDanielson - trying to find matches based on the user and the age properties. I would term it matching, not duplicates.

Comment: Interestingly, your original solution is the fastest by far. I think that it could produce duplicates if others has duplicates, but if you `return false;` after doing `result.push(n)` it should be ok.

Comment: @CoryDanielson - Good to know; what did you use for performance testing? The other answers have more syntactic sugar, but if this version is significantly faster, I'll continue on this route.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/testingdiwq I added more data, but if you trim the `others` you'll start to see a big difference between yours and mine. But it's negligible. It all happens very quickly regardless of solution. Gotta balance performance vs clean code. Clean code is usually better since most performance concerns are related to the DOM

Comment: @CoryDanielson - Awesome. If you want to add that to your answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can index the others, and then get the desired results without having to nest loops. It should be a relatively efficient solution, regardless of the amount of data:

```
// index others by "user + age"
var lookup = _.keyBy(others, function(o) { return o.user + o.age.toString() });
// find all users where "user + age" exists in index, one loop, quick lookup. no nested loops
var result = _.filter(users, function(u) {
    return lookup[u.user + u.age.toString()] !== undefined;
});
```

This gives the same result:

```
[
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 60, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 70, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 22, 'active': false }
];
```

Interestingly, your original solution was the most performant of all of these answers.

http://jsperf.com/testingdiwq

The performance concerns are pretty negligible here. In most cases, the DOM interaction is the main performance bottleneck of the front-end. If you were to run this against huge datasets and noticed the locking, you'd definitely want to optimize it further by using for loops instead of iterating with lodash functions.... but you won't typically come across that kind of data in JavaScript... SQL and others would handle it better.

Comment: Hmmm, could the creating of the lookup string as a sort of "magic string" lead to inadvertent problems? For the sake of argument, suppose users are integers and you have user 1 and user 11, and user 1 is the age of 11, and user 11 is the age of 1? Obviously this isn't realistic in the current data structure, but couldn't this type of mis-match exist in this format?

Comment: Yeah that could definitely happen under those circumstances. You'd have to do a tree or something to be safe from that kind of issue. The performance gain is negligible, though... unless this is being performed over a very large set of data, but in that case you'd have to switch to for loops to get good performance.

Comment: In your magic string, you could also use a separator between the user and age value, ie "user11-11" where "-" splits the user and age, to avoid that kind of issue

Comment: indexBy seems to have been renamed to keyBy

Comment: Note that using lookup method may actually be faster if you can initialize and keep the lookup array at the beginning of your code. The jsperf only show 1% difference slower but that's most likely because it has to create the lookup array every single time. It literally double the work for that test case.

Answer (score 10):

Here is cleaner way i can think of:

```
var result = _.flatten(_.map(others, function(item){
  return _.filter(users, item);
}));
```

*Edit:*
Apologies *JS Bin* output was obfuscating the nested array.

Comment: The syntax is nice and short, but that actually does not return the desired result. The desired result is an array of objects, not an array of arrays. The result here is an array of arrays.

Comment: Thanks; now returning objects.

Answer (score 5):

Using ES6 fat arrows and lodash's reject:

```
const result = _.reject(users, (item) => _.find(others, { user: item.user }));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = _.flatten(_.map(others, function(other){return _.where(users, other);}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lodash and ES6 syntax.

```
    const users = [
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
      { 'user': 'joe', 'age': 40, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 50, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 60, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 70, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 22, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 25, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 40, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
    ];

    const filters = [
      { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 60, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 70, 'active': false },
      { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 22, 'active': false }
    ];


    _.filter(users, ({user, age, active}) => {
        return _.findIndex(filters, ({user:filterUser, age:filterAge, active:filterActive}) => { return (user == filterUser && age == filterAge && active == filterActive) }) >= 0;
    })
```